# AWStats: cannot access /var/log/apache2/access.log

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, logging

I installed awstats on my new Ubuntu Lucid server, but when cron tries to run it as user `www-data`, it complains that `cannot access /var/log/apache2/access.log: Permission denied`.

In `/usr/share/doc/awstats/README.Debian` there's this paragraph:

> By default Apache stores (since
>   version 1.3.22-1) logfiles with
>   uid=root and gid=adm, so you need to
>   either...
>
> 1) Change the rights of the logfiles
>   in /etc/logrotate.d/apache so that
>       www-data has at least read access.
>
> 2) As 1) but change to a specific
>   user, and use the suEXEC feature of
>   Apache
>       to run as same user (and either change the right of /var/lib/awstats
>   as
>       well or use another directory). This is more complicated, but then the
>   logs
>       are not generally accessible to the server (which was probably the
>   point of
>       the Apache default).
>
> 3) Change awstats.pl to group adm
>   (but beware that you are then taking
>   the
>       risk of allowing a CGI-script access to admin stuff on the
>   machine!).

I'd go with 1, but what are the recommended permissions to grant?

Comment: Try this, cant promise if it will work: `chown www-data:www-data <yourFile>` and then `chmod 655 <yourFile>`.

Comment: Well to make awstats work it's enough to `chmod 755 /var/log/apache2` and `chmod 644 access.log`, but I'd like a "this is the best pratice"-kind of answer :) Thanks for chiming in though!

Comment: I think you're right to go with #1 (with just read access, unless there is something else awstats needs).   This gives access to a limited user account, and doesn't grant new access to anything beyond that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go for point 1 and it says that www-data should have at least read permission then the recomended is grant only read.

You can alter the line (in logrotate file):

```
create 640 root adm
```

to

```
create 644 root adm
```

To give all users (www-data included) read permission.

You'll need to change permissions existent files in /var/log/apache2/ to match this setting

```
chmod a+r /var/log/apache2/* #or whatever your path is
```

Then all the files can be read by all users and all the files that logrotate create in the future will have the adecuate permissions

Comment: And for "all users" to be able to look into "/var/log/apache2/" do aditionally: chmod a+x /var/log/apache2/

Comment: www-data should need to enter on the "/var/log/apache2" directory, but instead of adding permissions to all users I prefer to set the owner of the folder to www-date because root has always permissions. `chown www-data /var/log/apache2`

Answer (score 9):

In most setups:

- awstats runs as your apache user **www-data**;
- the apache log files are owned by **root:adm** and have
  **-rw-r-----** (aka: **chmod 640**) permissions; and
- the ownership and permissions settings can be found in the file
  **/etc/logrotate.d/apache2**, the contents of which is:

  ```
  /var/log/apache2/*.log {
      daily
      missingok
      rotate 60
      compress
      delaycompress
      notifempty
      dateext
      create 640 root adm
      sharedscripts
      postrotate
              /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
      endscript }
  ```

The simplest solution is to:

1) Change "**create 640 root adm**" to "**create 644 root adm**" in **/etc/logrotate.d/apache2** using your favorite text editor or, if you must script everything:

```
sudo sed -i 's/create 640 root adm/create 644 root adm/g' /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

2) Change the permissions on **/var/log/apache2/access.log** and **/var/log/apache2/error.log** to **644**.

```
sudo chmod 644 /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

3) Restart apache.

```
sudo apachectl -k graceful
```

I've seen people adding the www-data to the adm user group as a solution. That's a lot more permissions for **www-data** than I'm comfortable with.

Other more secure options involve creating a new user & groups for awstats and making awstats run/execute as this new user/group.

Comment: Yet another solution would be to change the group of `/var/log/apache2` and everything under it to `www-data` and make the files group-readable.  This is slightly less permissive than making them world-readable.